# I dont know why my authenticate method is not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, user-controls, web-development-server

I have a django project in which it has a custom user model, and I am able to use it to login properly.
But, in my registration form, I have the same code for logging the user in after he registers, but it doesn't actually log the user in, just create the account.

Please try to help me see what I am doing wrong. And if theres any way I can improve my code, please let me know.

Follows the code for the registration form, which register the user but doenst log it in. If anybody needs any extra piece of code, please ask me. Thanks ahead!

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'scheduling/registration_form.html'
    user = get_user_model()


    #display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # process form data
    def post(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            #cleaned (normalized) data

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            #returns User objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'scheduling/index.html', {})
                    #return redirect('scheduling:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Now, there's the code for the login, which is exactly the same on the userFormView() but it does log the user in.

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return render(request, 'scheduling/index.html', {})
            else:
                return render(request, 'scheduling/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'scheduling/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'scheduling/login.html')
```

And this is my user costom model:

```
# user class
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='email address',
    )
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='username'
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: Have you tried to `print(user)` after `authenticate`? It should print user object.

Comment: It is indeed giving me None

Comment: I was able to solve it! Thank you

Comment: You can also give answer to your own question. Explain in detail about how you solve it helps to other.

Comment: By answering your own question, you also let others know they don't need to look at this anymore